# python XlsxWriter: set font does not affect the appearance of cells in output excel file

Tags: excel, python-3.x, fonts, xlsxwriter

I have used XlsxWriter python package to produce an excel file from my data. I tried several way to apply my font 'B Nazanin' to cells:

```
title_cell_format.set_font_name('B Nazanin')
title_cell_format.set_font_family('B Nazanin')
title_cell_format.set_font('B Nazanin')
```

When I use one of these methods, I can see the font name, but the font appearance is not like "B Nazanin" in output excel file:[image]

I guessed the solution should be setting the text direction that can be done manually in excel in the following menu. Now the question is that how can I set this attribute in my python program!!
[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is undocumented, mainly because no-one ever asked for it, but you can set the cell text direction using the format `reading_order` property.

Right to left is reading order 2:

```
title_cell_format.set_reading_order(2)
```

**Update**:

This issue isn't related to the reading_order/text direction. It looks like it is more likely related to the charset of this particular font. The following requires the latest XlsxWriter code from GitHub but should fix the issue:

```
title_cell_format.set_font('B Nazanin')
title_cell_format.set_font_family(0)
title_cell_format.set_font_charset(178)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. I could change the direction with reading_order property. But unfortunately the main problem is still remained. changing the font_name does not affect the text appearance.

Comment: In that case you will have to submit a bug report to [Github](https://github.com/jmcnamara/XlsxWriter/issues) with a small, complete, working program that demonstrates the issue.